# Using libopc with iOS

Tags: ios, wordprocessingml, libopc

Hi I am working on an app which includes the work of word processing. I am trying to use [http://libopc.codeplex.com/](http://libopc.codeplex.com/%22libopc%22) for this purpose but I cannot find a proper way to do it. Can anyone point me in the right direction as how to achieve this.

I am able to load .docx file on webview. So, can I use `UIWebview` to do this?